# Change new-login-left and new-login-right to adhere to style and border

Tags: feature-request, design

Please could we change these divs:

[image]

To this:

[image]

By applying some simple css:

```
border-style:solid;
border-color:silver;
padding:10px !important;
border-width:1px;
```

The original design looks a tad busy and hard to read.  If we encapsulate it with a border and some padding it looks cleaner and easier on the eyes.

Comment: I have taken myself the freedom to "implement" this using [Stacks](https://stackoverfow.design), Stack Exchange's design system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H51h.png. The appropriate component for this seems to be *card*.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... - Yes but make the heights equal otherwise that looks odd!

Comment: well, that is strange. They have the same size in normal and I apply the same parent element...? I currently don't have the time to do an other mockup, maybe you can try? It is really easy. Just look at the stacks documentation. :) ?